# Android Creating touchscreen

Tags: android, project, touchscreen

```
private String TAG = GestureActivity.class.getSimpleName();

float initialX, initialY;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = event.getX();
            initialY = event.getY();
            AllocationAdapter imageView = null;

            imageView.setX((int) initialX);

            imageView.setY((int) initialY);

            Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I am receiving errors at this point.

Comment: what type of error you received?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please list the error you are receiving.

Comment: My application is stopped error

Comment: Search on this site for how to view logcat and how to read a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your object `imageView` is null, so you can't use imageView.setX() or imageView.setY().

You need to create one with the method :

- AllocationAdapter create1D (RenderScript rs, Allocation a)
- AllocationAdapter create2D (RenderScript rs, Allocation a)
- AllocationAdapter createTyped (RenderScript rs, Allocation a, Type t)

Comment: Are you a bit more about that you can give the site name

Comment: I get that from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/renderscript/AllocationAdapter.html) but it's seem to be an advanced concept. Maybe it's not what you really want. Can you explain what is the use of the touch ?

Comment: Touching the object will go in that direction finger

Comment: I'm guessing it's an imageView you are trying to move. [Maybe look here for what you want.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557076/how-to-smoothly-move-a-image-view-with-users-finger-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred in this line

```
imageView.setX((int) initialX);
```

because your trying to set value for `null` object

Initialize the `imageView`

Comment: Where in the code identifies whether imageView.setX((int) initialX);