# How to move an image to touch location?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a start screen where the user can move a character around (Image).

I've written some code that I think is correct, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I run the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        image.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    }

    View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                image.setX(event.getX());
                image.setY(event.getY());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

When I run the app the image doesn't move on touch or at all.

Comment: Here's this link which help you to get your desire output
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557076/how-to-smoothly-move-a-image-view-with-users-finger-on-android-emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557076/how-to-smoothly-move-a-image-view-with-users-finger-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of image view add touch listener to the layout 
Example:
activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        constrainLayout.setOnTouchListener(touchListener)
    }

    var touchListener: OnTouchListener = OnTouchListener { v, event ->
        val action = event.action
        imageView.x = event.x
        imageView.y = event.y
        false
    }

}
```